# If a Result returns Err(_), I want the whole function to return a HTTP request error

Tags: rust, iron

I'm trying to use the Iron framework to build a simple backend in Rust. This handler is just supposed to return the content of a certain file and I can get it to work properly with `unwrap()` but I want to try to do proper error handling. This is how I would imagine it would look like:

```
fn get_content(res: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let mut id = String::new();
    res.body.read_to_string(&mut id).unwrap();

    let file_path_string = &("../content/".to_string() + &id + ".rdt");

    // TODO: Error handling
    match File::open(file_path_string) {
        Ok(f) => {
            let mut s = String::new();
            f.read_to_string(&mut s);
            Ok(Response::with(((status::Ok), s)))
        }
        Err(err) => Err(Response::with(((status::InternalServerError), "File not found")))
    };
}
```

This throws the error `not all control paths return a value [E0269]`, which is fine. But if I add a response after the match part:

```
match File::open(file_path_string) {
    Ok(f) => {
        let mut s = String::new();
        f.read_to_string(&mut s);
        Ok(Response::with(((status::Ok), s)))
    }
    Err(err) => Err(Response::with(((status::InternalServerError), "File not found")))
};

Err(Response::with(((status::InternalServerError), "File not found")))
```

I instead get the error message:

```
expected `iron::error::IronError`,
    found `iron::response::Response`
(expected struct `iron::error::IronError`,
    found struct `iron::response::Response`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:95        
Err(Response::with(((status::InternalServerError), "File not found")))
```

I think the problem is the collision between Rust Err and Iron Err? I'm not sure though. And I have not done much web development (or Rust for that matter) in the past so any feedback on the code is also appreciated!

UPDATE: I think this is more "The Rust Way" to do it? But I'm not sure

```
fn get_content(res: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let mut id = String::new();
    res.body.read_to_string(&mut id).unwrap();

    let file_path_string = &("../content/".to_string() + &id + ".rdt");

    // TODO: Error handling
    let f;
    match File::open(file_path_string) {
        Ok(file) => f = file,
        Err(err) => Err(HttpError::Io(err))
    };
    let mut s = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut s);
    Ok(Response::with(((status::Ok), s)))
}
```

Having the code inside the error handling seems weird as `read_to_string` also needs to be taken care of and that would create a nested mess of error handling? However, these matching arms are obviously of incompatible types so it won't work... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Ok()` takes an `Response`, but an `Err()` takes an `IronError`.

Hence your call `Err(...)` is not valid when `...` is a `Response`!

How to correct it? Well the first step is, you must create an `IronError` to send back. I believe (not familiar with Iron) that Iron will automatically an appropriate error code and that it's not your job to do that. In the documentation we find one key type implementing `IronError`:

```
pub enum HttpError {
    Method,
    Uri(ParseError),
    Version,
    Header,
    TooLarge,
    Status,
    Io(Error),
    Ssl(Box<Error + 'static + Send + Sync>),
    Http2(HttpError),
    Utf8(Utf8Error),
    // some variants omitted
}
```

I can't see one which allows for an arbitrary string like "file not found". However, your use case is one of an IO failure, right? So it would make sense to use `HttpError::Io` with the `std::IoError` that you got back from `File::open()`:

```
match File::open(file_path_string) {
    Ok(f) => {
        let mut s = String::new();
        f.read_to_string(&mut s);
        Ok(Response::with(((status::Ok), s)))
    }
    Err(err) => Err(HttpError::Io(err))
};
```

By the way, it also fixes your "TODO: error handling"! How beautiful!

(Code untested, please feel free to edit if compilation fails)

Comment: Is it idiomatically correct to do the rest of the code part inside the error handling? Considering I need to handle the result of ```read_to_string```, won't it create a nested mess of error handling?

Comment: What would be idiomatic, I guess, is to first see if the `try!` macro is applicable (I don't know if it is with Iron's Error types and/or your function's signature.) If it's not, a good workaround would be to structure as follows: `let what_you_want = match ... { ... }` and 1. make the Ok branch end with what_you_want 2. early-return from the Err branch. This way you can continue below without nesting. Actually, this is the philosophy behind `try!`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use `try!` at first but there was some sort of collision with the Iron package. Is the solution simply to abandon `try!` or can you work around this? I also tried the `let what_you_want = match` approach but ended up in a mess of arms not having matching types. What is an early return? Is it simply adding return? `return Err(HttpError::Io(err))`? Because the problem I get then is that I'm returning an `hyper::error:Error` but it's expeting a `iron::error::IronError`...

Comment: By "early return", yes I mean simply adding return, as you describe. As for your latter problem, I took a look at Iron examples; I'm not sure and I don't have a setup to test it right now, but maybe try `return IronError::new(HttpError::Io(err), status::InternalServerError)`?

Comment: Thank you! I got it working! I had to add `Err(...)` around your suggestion but now it works!